# Ionic com admob-free anuncio exibe somente "Nice Job"

Tags: ionic, ionic3, ionic2, admob, ionic-popup

Criei uma aplicação com ionic versão: `3.20.1` e configurei com o admobfree:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-admob-free --save --variable ADMOB_APP_ID="ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXXX"

ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-admob-free --save --variable ADMOB_APP_ID="ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXXX"
```

Ele já esta incluso no `config.xml`

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-admob-free" spec="0.25.0">
    <variable name="ADMOB_APP_ID" value="ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXXX" />
</plugin>
```

E no meu TS estão com todas as configurações solicitadas:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { BarcodeScanner, BarcodeScannerOptions, BarcodeScanResult } from '@ionic-native/barcode-scanner';
import { ScanResultPage } from '../scan-result/scan-result';
import { AdMobFree, AdMobFreeBannerConfig } from '@ionic-native/admob-free';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor(
    private platform:Platform,
    public navCtrl: NavController,
    private barcodeScanner: BarcodeScanner,
    private admobFree: AdMobFree) {

    let bannerConfig: AdMobFreeBannerConfig = {
      autoShow: true,
     id : 'ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXXX'
    };
    this.admobFree.banner.config(bannerConfig);

    this.admobFree.banner.prepare().then(() => {
    }).catch(e => alert(e));
  }
```

O anuncio aparece, mais fica só mostrando o anuncio de de teste:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém sabe como posso proceder ?

> Atualizado: 02/03/2019

Tentei ver com esse plugin também, mais sem sucesso:
[Using Admob With Ionic Framework](https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2014/06/using-admob-ionicframework/)

Comment: testou com `isTesting: false` ?

Comment: Sim, sem scesso

Answer (score 1):

Provavelmente voce esta usando um *id* de testes, para fazer funcionar você precisa criar uma conta. Apos criar a conta use o ID nela criada. Isso fará que voce possa personalizar quais anúncios devem ser exibidos e mostrará os anúncios reais.

Altere seu appId dentro de `config.xml`, mas pode levar um tempo ate funcionar,  provavelmente um dia ou mais para começar a mostrar os anúncios.

> Fonte: [@soEn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45934027/10514656)

Comment: Na verdade eu já estou com a conta criada e o anúncio também. É o Id já é de produção, inclusive foi na parte do admob que vincula o anúncio ao App na Google play

Comment: Tente apagar os comentarios para nao virar um forum, digo "rodando" em relacao a qual comando voce esta executando para abrir o ionic? Ionic run? ou usando o release para lancar o app?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29489287/admob-only-sends-test-ad-not-real-ads?rq=1 aqui fala sobre nao rodar em simuladores ou em debug

Comment: Entendi, então, tanto rodando o run com livereload , tanto como release e inclusive após hospedado na loja e feito o download do App da a mesma coisa, vou olhar o link enviado. Obrigado